# Restart explorer.exe and restore windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, directory

I wrote a simple batch script that kills explorer.exe and then start it again. Its a common operation that I need for the Windows client software I'm developing.

The negative side effect is that any opened explorer window is closed and I need to manually open it up.

I want to add some pre and post operation to my script that will restore the opened Windows.

Best case would be if we could keep the commands in the form of a batch script, though I suppose it would be much simpler to implement using C#.

Comment: Just curious here why your client software has to kill explorer?

Comment: I'm overriding explorer's icons. Any change to my software would require restart for the changes to take effect

Comment: ok. What would you want to happen if the user had a dozen different windows open?

Comment: I'm the user, this is just for debugging. My release won't need restart except for the first time, after the installation.

Comment: ok. Then do you have a specific window opened, and you want to reopen?

Comment: No specific window. Any window that may be currently opened.

Comment: Here is a nifty open-source utility, [cmdow](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/), which was develped specifically to read and manipulate explorer windows using batch files. Using it, you can get the names of each open folder before shutdown.